# Вывод словаря без дополнительных знаков

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть ли возможность вывести весь словарь без дополнительных симолов (без запятых, кадратных и фигурных скобок) прямо из переменной, не прибегая к итерации? Также важно не задеть данные в самом словаре, например, ссылки, цифры и т.д...

При помощи парсинга с сайта по номеру варианта, в словарь заносятся некоторые ответы на решение примеров. Например, спарсив номера, я имею словарь

```
data = {'a':2, 'b':{'x':3, 'y':{'t1': 4, 't2':5}}}
```

а нужно вывести это вот так:

```
>>> data

a: 2
b:
  x: 3
  y:
    t1: 4
    t2: 5
```

Comment: Не прибегая к итерации - никак

Comment: Что Вы имели в виду под _"не прибегая к итерации"_? Нельзя использовать циклы? Это довольно странное условие, зачем Вам это?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Такая необходимость нужна чтобы все данные были отправлены пользователю в одном сообщении при помощи VK API

Comment: В таком случае, вы, похоже, какое-то очень странное значение вкладываете во фразу "не прибегая к итерации"...

Comment: Похоже, здесь проблема XY. Можете объяснить подробно, что вам нужно сделать и почему вам нельзя использовать итерацию?

Comment: @Xander Так как данные, которые будут находиться в словаре нужны для пользователя, я решил, что будет проще прочистить весь словарь от скоб и запятых при помощи `replace`. Но появилась проблема: в значениях может находиться запятая или другой символ, который будет удален.
Итерацию я исключил из-за того, что данный словарь необоходимо вывести из переменной, а как знаю я, результат итерации невозможно записать в переменную. Как-то так

Comment: С записью результата итерации в переменную нет никаких проблем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, смотрите, даже с итерацией всё великолепно записывается в переменную.

```
data = {'a':2, 'b':{'x':3, 'y':{'t1': 4, 't2':5}}}

def serialize(dct, tabs=0):
    res = []
    pref = ' ' * 2 * tabs
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            res += [pref + str(k) + ':']
            res += [serialize(v, tabs+1)]
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            res = [pref + str(k) + ': ' + ', '.join(map(str,v))]
        else:
            res += [pref + str(k) + ': ' + str(v)]
    return '\n'.join(res)


result = serialize(data)

print(result)
```