# Как мне избавиться от фигурных скобок вокруг вывода запроса?

Tags: python, база-данных, pymysql

Возник весьма резонный вопрос - как избавиться от фигурных скобок вокруг запроса? Код следующий:

```py
    def user_money(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            user_mny = "SELECT money FROM users WHERE user_id = (%s)"
            result = self.cursor.execute(user_mny, (user_id))
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()
            if result in self.cursor is not None:
                print(result)
                return int(result[0)
            else:
                result = result[0]
                print(result)
                print("!")
            self.connection.close
```

Вывод:

```py
{'money': 0}
```

использую pymysql

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод словаря без дополнительных знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1073038/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: `if result in self.cursor is not None:` эээ, какое-то странное условие, нет?